# How to generate a model after running a migration on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I have created a migration file as follows before generating a model , viewer or a controller

```
class Papaers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
   create_table :papers do |t|
   t.integer :unit_id, :null=>false
   t.integer :document_id, :null=>false
   t.timestamps
 end
end

 def self.down
   drop_table :papers
 end
end
```

This ran well and it create the table. But now I want to create a model for this table. Is there  a way in rails to create a model after running migration files? I could not see any model generated under papers in model.

Comment: How did you created the above `migration` ?

Comment: generate a migration file added the fields and ran it

Comment: Obviously this is an old question but in case anyone happens on this in their search: Per the Rails naming conventions, the model name should be *singular*. Rails will know it corresponds to the plural version in the database. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#naming-conventions

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`rails g model Papaers --migration=false`

Or you can also give

`rails g model Papaers`

Rails generator would not overwrite if migration already exists.

Answer (score 12):

```
rails g model Papaers --skip-migration
```

The `--skip-migration` flag can also be used to generate a model without generating the migration file.